# CASE statement not picking up NULL value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I wrote the following CASE statement

```
CASE PaymentType
  WHEN NULL THEN 'Check'
  WHEN 512 THEN 'Check'
  WHEN 0 THEN 'Check'
  WHEN 32 THEN 'ACH'
  WHEN 544 THEN 'ACH'
  ELSE 'Card'
  END AS 'Current Acceptance',
```

NULL values though are falling into the ELSE category (i.e. card), not 'Check' as expected.

What would be a simple to change this so that NULL values returned 'check'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't work.  `NULL` doesn't even match `NULL` in a `case` expression.

Use explicit comparisons:

```
(CASE WHEN PaymentType IS NULL OR
           PaymentType IN (512, 0)
      THEN 'Check'
      WHEN PaymentTYpe IN (32, 544)
      THEN 'ACH'
      ELSE 'Card'
 END) AS Current_Acceptance,
```

Comment: I had no idea being explicit would make a difference - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think TSQL is picky about "= NULL" vs "IS NULL" in this case.

Try this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN PaymentType IS NULL THEN 'Check'
  WHEN PaymentType = 512 THEN 'Check'
  WHEN PaymentType = 0 THEN 'Check'
  WHEN PaymentType = 32 THEN 'ACH'
  WHEN PaymentType = 544 THEN 'ACH'
  ELSE 'Card'
 END AS 'Current Acceptance'
```

Comment: Oh wow - so I had backed out Gordon's answer, to *exactly* this.  He had added a a bit more elegance, which when removed, is exactly your answer.